# Moto Maxx with android 6.0.1 takes random pictures upon on/off button pressing:

Tags: lock-screens, camera, power-on

There is something prompting the camera of my cellphone to take a picture whenever I try to block it. The blocking does occur but a picture is taken.  I took a look on the system UI configs and nothing different is set. How do I check which actions are assigned to my on off/button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check under Display and disable the highlighted button. This is on Moto X Play and I think you should find it there in your device too

[image]

Comment: Glad to be of help. No Genius. I own Moto X Play. Thanks for accepting